# warning: pointer targets in passing argument 1 of '__builtin___strncpy_chk' differ in signedness

Tags: c

I am getting a warning for the below code.

```
//someother class 
#define EVENT_ID_DESCRIPTION_LEN  64
struct FILE_DESCRIPTIONS
{
    uint32_t  uFileID;
    uint32_t  uDescriptionLen; 
    int8_t   szDescription[FILE_ID_DESCRIPTION_LEN];
};

//defined inside a function of someother class
int8_t  chTemp[EVENT_ID_DESCRIPTION_LEN + 1];
strncpy(chTemp,pMsg->st.aDescriptions[nIndex].szDescription,EVENT_ID_DESCRIPTION_LEN);
```

**warning: pointer targets in passing argument 1 of '_*builtin*__strncpy_chk' differ in signedness**

The value from which i'm storing from is also uint8_t and that gets stored onto is also uint8_t.what might be the cause of this warning.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems this question has been answered, don't you agree?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, your code is defining **int8_t** (signed int) and not **uint8_t** (unsigned int) as you think. Did you spotted it?

You have to change your variable to:

```
uint8_t  chTemp[EVENT_ID_DESCRIPTION_LEN + 1];
```

Answer (score 3):

Remember that in C, the three types `char`, `unsigned char` and `signed char` are all distinct, and `strncpy` expects a `char`. If your `int8_t` is defined as `signed char`, you have conflicting types. Best to use an actual `char`, non?

Answer (score 1):

Can't you use `memcpy` instead?

```
memcpy(chTemp, pMsg->st.aDescriptions[nIndex].szDescription, EVENT_ID_DESCRIPTION_LEN);
```